# Determine whether this map $\phi$ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

$\langle M_2 (\mathbb{R}), \cdot \rangle$ with $\langle \mathbb{R}, \cdot \rangle$ where $\phi(A)$ is the determinant of matrix $A$.

I don't believe the map is an isomorphism because  I don't think it is injective (one-to-one). I know that if a matrix is not invertible, then the determinant will always be 0 and that the $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$. However I am having a hard time backing up my answer and explaining what I know to show that the map is not an isomorphism. Here is what I have so far.

> Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ Matrix and let B be the transpose of A. Then $\phi(A) = \det(A) = \det(B) = \phi(B)$.

Is this sufficient enough to show that the map is not injective?

Comment: I would just pick a specific $A$ and $B$. For instance, there are some matrices that equal their own transpose, and 1-1 would still hold in that case. Other than that, showing it's not injective is sufficient to prove it's not an isomorphism.

Comment: Something else to consider: is the group $(M_2(\mathbb R), \cdot)$ abelian? What about $(\mathbb R, \cdot)$?

Comment: Your proof is sufficient as long as $B \ne A$.  So find a non-symmetric matrix.

Comment: @BrianS I have not learned about abelian groups yet. Based off my very little information, I believe that to be abelian, you must have the multiplicative commutative property, which the group $M_2(\mathbb{R}),\cdot)$ would not have, but $(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$ would .

@@Tartaglia'sStutter I see, so just using a counter example is fine rather than trying to make a genealized statement

Comment: @EvanKim In the context of groups, *abelian* simply means commutative.

Comment: @EvanKim Your are absolutely correct. The fact the real numbers commute over multiplication while matrices generally do not can be used to prove that no isomorphism can exist between $(M_2(\mathbb R), \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb R, \cdot)$. I added an answer below that presents one such proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show a map is not injective, all you need to do is find two inputs that map for the same output. In this case, the following matrices have the same determinant:
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
, &&
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
So the map is not injective (hence not an isomorphism).

Answer (score 4):

Others have commented on the proof that you have presented. I will present an alternative proof in case it proves helpful.

Let us suppose that $\phi: M_2(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ is an isomorphism. Then its inverse, $\phi^{-1}: \mathbb R \to M_2(\mathbb R)$ must also be an isomorphism.

Now, pick two matrices $H_1, H_2 \in M_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $H_1 H_2 \neq H_2 H_1$. Since $\phi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism, it must also be surjective, so there exists elements $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $\phi^{-1}(n_1) = H_1$ and $\phi^{-1}(n_2) = H_2$. Therefore, we have
$$
H_1 H_2 = \phi^{-1}(n_1) \phi^{-1}(n_2) = \phi^{-1}(n_1 n_2)
$$

Since real numbers commute (meaning that the group $(\mathbb R, \cdot)$ is abelian), $n_1 n_2 = n_2 n_1$. Hence,
$$
\phi^{-1}(n_1 n_2) = \phi^{-1}(n_2 n_1).
$$

Once more applying the properties of an isomorphism gives us
$$
\phi^{-1}(n_2 n_1) = \phi^{-1}(n_2)\phi^{-1}(n_1) = H_2 H_1.
$$
Therefore,
$$
H_1 H_2 = H_2 H_1.
$$
which contradicts the condition that $H_1 H_2 \neq H_2 H_1$, so our assumption that $\phi$ is an isomorphism must be false.

Comment: Not a direct answer to my question, but I enjoyed reading the proof by contradiction :) Thanks for sharing!

Comment: A shorter way to say the same thing is that isomorphisms preserve commutativity, but $\mathbb R$ is abelian and not the group of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it's a group isomorphism. Then there is a group homomorphism $\psi$ s.t. $\psi (\phi(x)) = x$ and $x = \phi(\psi(x))$. Take any two real numbers, $a$ and $b$. Since $ab$ = $ba$, $\psi(ab) = \psi(ba)$. $\psi(ab) = \psi(a)\cdot\psi(b) = \psi(b)\cdot\psi(a)$. Since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary and $\psi$ is bijection, $\psi(a)$ and $\psi(b)$ are arbitrary, thus for any matrices $A$ and $B$, they commute. This is false though.

Comment: Note: it doesn't make sense to write $\psi(\phi(x)) = x = \phi(\psi(x))$, as you have; the left and right sides are from disjoint sets, so they cannot be equal.

Comment: @Sambo yes, I fixed it.